# Tool to remove security from PDF documents

Tags: gratis, pdf, offline, security

I have a PDF which is password-protected (40-bit RC4), which I need to modify. Needless to say, I don't know the password.

I'm looking for a software which can either unprotect such PDF documents, or edit them regardless of the protection. Additional requirements:

- edited PDF should have a reasonable size (i.e. I can print to TIFF and edit at will, but I hope for a better option)
- software should operate offline (the PDF contains sensitive information and cannot be uploaded to online service)
- parts of the PDF which I didn't edit should remain unchanged when printed.
- Linux support is preferred, but Windows is fine too.

Use case: providing a bank statement for the expense report, while removing lines I don't want to share with my employer (like online banking access code).

Answer (score 1):

[DocDocGoose](https://docdocgoose.huey.xyz) is a web app that allows you to unprotect such documents or remove such edit restrictions, without the original password. The processing within your browser and the document is never uploaded to an online service.

DocDocGoose doesn't allow you to edit the PDF directly after unprotecting it at the moment (this is still in the works), so you will have to use other software for that.

Since it is a web app, it will work on Linux, Windows, macOS, or any other platform with a modern web browser.

Disclaimer: I am the author of DocDocGoose.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll check it out on the next occasion.